# mongoose failed with node 17. mongoDb+node database connection failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have node project.
It has connection to my mongoDb with mongoose.
When I upgrade my node from version 16 to version 18 it stopped to connect to the DB.afterwards i figured out that there id such problem fron node v 17, but i didn't found a solution that solve my problem.

I run the server with npm start.
It comes to to the connect function. On Node v 16 it succeede,
but on v 18 it failed to the catch.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const { MONGO_URI } = process.env;

exports.connect = () => {
  // Connecting to the database
  mongoose
    .connect(MONGO_URI)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Successfully connected to database");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("database connection failed. exiting now...");
      console.error(error);
      process.exit(1);
    });
};
```

[image]